# Set PrintArea To "Print Entire Workbook" Using EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, epplus

The Excel Print Preview UI has a 3 print settings:

1. Print Active Sheets
2. Print Entire Workbook
3. Print Selection

I'm generating an Excel Workbook on the fly using `EPPlus` and would like to have the `Print Entire Workbook` option selected by default. I do not see where to set this in the `PrintArea` setting.

I tried setting it in the UI, saving the workbook locally and opening it with EPPlus and the `PrintArea` of each `Worksheet` was null. Setting the `PrintArea` to null does not change this print setting, it remains `Print Active Sheets`.

How do I set the `Print Entire Workbook` print setting using `EPPlus`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further testing, this does not appear to be possible.

Even after selecting "Print Entire Workbook", saving the `Workbook`, closing it, and reopening it, the default "Print Active Sheets" is selected so this leads me to believe that this setting is not stored anywhere in the actual file, just stored within the Excel "session".

Comment: That's... interesting. Pretty lame :(

Comment: @TranquilMarmot not lame at all, that's the expected behaviour. Just as you don't expect `Print Page 3` to be a Word document setting, `Print All Sheets` isnt' an Excel document setting. It's only meaningful for the *current print operation*. *Print* always asks you what to do. *Quick Print* prints the active sheet, which is the sensible default. I suspect the OP wanted to ask how to programatically print Excel documents but asked about his failed attempt instead.